# Getting a SQL error code when doing a SELECT INTO

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am doing a `select into` inside my RPGLE. It was working all good in development but it started giving me a SQL error when deployed to production. SQL Error is:

> -579 (object-type object-name ATTEMPTED TO READ DATA WHEN THE DEFINITION OF THE FUNCTION OR PROCEDURE DID NOT SPECIFY THIS ACTION).

Note that TABLE1 (which was also changed, added a field, for this Request and moved to production along with the Program) is only used in the below statement and not declared in F-spec.

Tried to recreate this in Development Environment but without Luck. This program is called from multiple programs but they do not create a job log for those. The call stack always has a Stored Procedure at the beginning (the Program is always called from an SP)

I think it has to do with some settings in the calling programs may be.

```
Exec Sql Select WHS                            
           into :WHS1                         
           from Table1
           Where Company = :COMP
             and WHS = :WHSE;
```

Comment: Are you using a Function? If the scalar function or table function returns a query, the function MUST have a data access classification of READS SQL DATA or MODIFIES SQL DATA. TABLE1 is a TABLE FUNCTION? If yes you also must change your sql...

Comment: Hi, Actually this program is called from Multiple Stored Procedures.  Some of them has "CONTAINS SQL" and some dont. Initially, I thought that it could be the issue. Then I created a SP and a Program(Which has SQL statement). I tried all combinations(READS SQL DATA,MODIFIES SQL DATA ,CONTAINS SQL ) but I did not get the error.  When I used NO SQL , it gave me a -487 SQLCODE whcih is very similar to -579

Comment: I just could recreate this. I created an SP with "CONTAINS SQL" which calls an RPG with a SQL statement. SP: "CREATE PROCEDURE &LIB/JJTESTSP ()          
EXTERNAL NAME &LIB/JJTESTRPG               
LANGUAGE RPGLE                             
CONTAINS SQL" The SQL in the RPG gave me a -579. I am a little confused here. this says that it Contains SQL. Then why would it break in the RPG? If I remove "CONTAINS SQL", it would not break

Comment: First off, `CONTAINS SQL` isn't going to work here.  It needs at LEAST `READS SQL DATA` because you are reading data from a table.  The reason it doesn't break if you remove `CONTAINS SQL` is because it defaults to `MODIFIES SQL` which is greater permissions than `CONTAINS SQL`.  Also, can you please expand your explanation?  According to your comment, this is being called from a stored procedure?  Please put that in the question along with the settings used to create the stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have updated the question(While writing the question, I did not know the importance of Stored Proc in this scenario )

Answer (score 2):

This program is called from Multiple Stored Procs. Some of them have a `Contains SQL` in it.

`CONTAINS SQL` means that the function may contain some SQL, but it does not read or write any data stored in a database via SQL. Examples include SET. With `CONTAINS SQL` in a stored procedure, if the procedure or one it calls tries to read a DB using SQL, then it fails. If it does not have `CONTAINS SQL`, then the stored procedure would take `MODIFIES SQL DATA` by default and it would not fail.

Comment: I updated the answer to remove implied inaccuracies. Specifically: RPG procedures called by a stored procedure can update the database even if the stored procedure is defined with `CONTAINS SQL`. However, those updates must be done using traditional record level access rather than SQL.

Comment: Thanks a Lot Mark. Actually, the fix I did was to make it CHAIN instead of SQL and it worked!